# Why does the "Ask Question" button have two different colors?

Tags: discussion, design, asking-questions

The color changes in both the main site and the meta:

## On question lists

[image]
[image]

## On question editing panels

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on the "Ask Question" page, the "Ask Question" button is actually disabled; clicking on it does nothing.

The different color is an intentional feature to highlight that you are currently asking a question and not viewing questions. There's a potential added intent that the color indicates that the button has been disabled.

Comment: hmm, but shouldn't the disabled button have darker color? This is reversed.